# Only calling the OnDestroy() of the mainActivity

Tags: java, android, networking, ondestroy

I am building an app that allows you to send files to other apps through a server. The thing is that when one of them closes the app by swiping it off, i want to send a disconnect message to the server.

The problem is that imagine that on the stack i have activities A (MainActivity) , B , C and D. If I am in the activity D and I swipe the app off (turn off the app), it will call the OnDestroy() method from the MainActivity. From the MainActivity, i can't send that disconnect message, so my question is **why isn't the onDestroy() from the other activities called ?**

PS: I could send the disconnect message from the MainActivity, but what if the person didn't reach the server part of the app? What if the person didn't try the part of the app that lets them send and receive files ? I would be sending a disconnect message for something that doesn't even exist.

**Or would there be any way where I could check, from within the MainActivity, if the activity D exists ?**

Comment: Is the code for sending file in an Activity? If yes, then you should consider doing so using Service.

Comment: Yes, i am already using a service, so i could trigger it from within the MainActivity. The problem is that if the person didn't use the service before (to send or receive) i shouldn't be trying to send a disconnect message. So i only have two options, either i can call the OnDestroy of the earlier activities or the onDestroy of the service (they are not being called) , or i have to find a way to know if the person already has a connection made, so that i don't try to send a disconnect message while there is no server

Comment: If the service is bounded service then it will also get destroyed when the Activity gets destroyed. You should be getting a callback for that in onDestroyed of Service.

Comment: I am only getting the onDestroy() from the MainActivity. I don't know why the onDestroy from the other activities are not being called

Comment: Have you checked if your Service onDestroyed is getting called or not?

Comment: I tried it, but it isn't being called